# How can I monitor health of SSH tunnel with Pexpect?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

I got an SSH tunnel done with `Pexpect` module which I'm only allowed to read from. How can I check if the connection is still up and running e.g. if there was any network connection issue in the meantime? The other side of my tunnel sends messages randomly so there may be like one day without any data in the stream. I've checked `pexpect.isalive()` function but it seems like it doesn't detect that the network connection is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `ssh`'s `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` options:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 user@host ...
```

If your `ssh` server does not support these options you can still try `TCPKeepAlive`:

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=yes user@host ...
```

And then in your `pexpect` script you only need to check `pexpect.EOF`.

---

The following is from `ssh_config` man page:

```
 ServerAliveCountMax
         Sets the number of server alive messages (see below) which may be
         sent without ssh(1) receiving any messages back from the server.
         If this threshold is reached while server alive messages are
         being sent, ssh will disconnect from the server, terminating the
         session.  It is important to note that the use of server alive
         messages is very different from TCPKeepAlive (below).  The server
         alive messages are sent through the encrypted channel and there-
         fore will not be spoofable.  The TCP keepalive option enabled by
         TCPKeepAlive is spoofable.  The server alive mechanism is valu-
         able when the client or server depend on knowing when a connec-
         tion has become inactive.

         The default value is 3.  This option applies to protocol
         version 2 only.

 ServerAliveInterval
         Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has
         been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through
         the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The
         default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to
         the server.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

 TCPKeepAlive
         Specifies whether the system should send TCP keepalive messages
         to the other side.  If they are sent, death of the connection or
         crash of one of the machines will be properly noticed.  However,
         this means that connections will die if the route is down tempo-
         rarily, and some people find it annoying.

         The default is ``yes'' (to send TCP keepalive messages), and the
         client will notice if the network goes down or the remote host
         dies.  This is important in scripts, and many users want it too.
```

Comment: `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3` worked for me, thanks!